# DatabaseMetaData#getColumns returns an empty ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, metadata

I'm having an issue retrieving metadata from a MySQL connection, running locally, Ubuntu 14, with Java and NetBeans. I get an empty ResultSet from the `getColumns` method of a `DatabaseMetaData` object.

The code is the following:

```
private static HashMap getColumnsFromDB(Connection con, String dbSchema, String tableName)    throws SQLException 
{
    HashMap Columns = new HashMap();

    DatabaseMetaData metadata = con.getMetaData();

    ResultSet rsColumns = metadata. getColumns(null, dbSchema.toUpperCase(), tableName.toUpperCase(), "%");

    while (rsColumns.next())
    {
        ColumnClass col = new ColumnClass();
        col.column_name = rsColumns.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
       col.mw_type =  UtilClass.toClass(rsColumns.getInt("DATA_TYPE"));   // Convert to java type
        col.is_nullable = rsColumns.getString("IS_NULLABLE");
        col.column_default = rsColumns.getString("COLUMN_DEF");

        Columns.put( col.column_name, col);
    }

    return Columns;
}
```

I can do queries to the database normally, the user is DBA, the table has columns, I've seen in others questions that it can be a little tricky with cases and so on, but I have tried in many ways and I had no expected results.

Answer (score 2):

With MySQL, the terms "Schema" and "Database" mean the same thing. Testing indicates that MySQL Connector/J does not pay any attention to the `schemaPattern` parameter of the `DatabaseMetaData#getColumns` method.

So, if you use a connection string like

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/db1
```

and then try to retrieve information about the columns of a table in the "schema" ("database") named `db2` with

```java
DatabaseMetaData metadata = con.getMetaData();
ResultSet rsColumns = metadata.getColumns(null, "db2", "mytable", "%");
```

you will get an empty ResultSet if there is no table named `mytable` in database `db1`. In order to retrieve the information for the table in `db2` you either need to use the `catalog` parameter

```java
DatabaseMetaData metadata = con.getMetaData();
ResultSet rsColumns = metadata.getColumns("db2", null, "mytable", "%");
```

or change the current database with `setCatalog`

```java
con.setCatalog("db2");
DatabaseMetaData metadata = con.getMetaData();
ResultSet rsColumns = metadata.getColumns(null, null, "mytable", "%");
```

Note that the second argument – `schemaPattern` – is `null` in the above two working examples, but in fact it can be anything; it is simply ignored.

**Edit re: comments**

OP reports that setting the `catalog` parameter is indeed the required approach, and that table – and, presumably, column – names appear to be case-sensitive under Linux. (My tests indicate that such names are *not* case-sensitive under Windows.)

Comment: It doesn't work. I suspect that it can be something wrong with the driver, in any case I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, mysql 5.5, jdbc 5.1.35, jdk 1.8 and netbeans 8.0.2, in case someone knows some compatibility issue.

Comment: What does `con.getCatalog()` return? The expected database name? An empty string? `null`?

Comment: It is an empty string, in the method call. After con.setCatalog() it takes the given value ("Users" in this case), but still returns an empty set. When I query the information schema database, all tables have the value "def" in the column TABLE_CATALOG (I think it means something like 'default'). I'm using this by now as a workaround.

Comment: So `ResultSet rsColumns = metadata.getColumns("Users", null, null, null);` gives you an empty ResultSet?

Comment: It worked. You find the solution. Finally, the last parameter, columnname, must be null (the value "%" is what doesn't work). The working code is at the end: ResultSet rsColumns = metadata. getColumns(null,dbSchema,tableName,null); Thank you Gord!

Comment: I'm back. I did many different tests that I got lost. What finally worked was setting the Catalog name, as you said. '"%"' worked as well at last. And the upper case doesn't work. In my case, table_name IS case sensitive (I've read in other realted posts about this, and other people claims the need to convert to upper case). So, I hope this is the end.